# Better way calculate percentage from class properties using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

We have the following definition LINQ:

```
myList.Select(s=> new DtoTest()
{
    TotalSamples = myList.Count(c=> c.UserId == s.UserId),
    EvaluatedSamples = myList.Count(c=> c.UserId == s.UserId && c.Status == Status.OK)
    PercentageRealized = (myList.Count(c=> c.UserId == s.UserId) / myList.Count(c=> c.UserId == s.UserId && c.Status == Status.OK)) * 100
});
```

Is there a way where you can assign the property value "PercentageRealized" without using the same functions previously used in: "TotalSamples" & "EvaluatedSamples"?

Something like that:

```
myList.Select(s=> new DtoTest()
{
    TotalSamples = myList.Count(c=> c.UserId == s.UserId),
    EvaluatedSamples = myList.Count(c=> c.UserId == s.UserId && c.Status == Status.OK)
    PercentageRealized = (TotalSamples / EvaluatedSamples) * 100 //<-!Not possible!
});
```

Any other tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing seems extremely questionable to me - you are making multiple passes over the source data to re-compute the same thing over and over again (per occurrence of `UserId`), when it seems like what you should want is to compute once per `UserId`, like so:

```
var ans2 = myList.GroupBy(s => s.UserId)
                .Select(sg => {
                    var ts = sg.Count();
                    var es = sg.Count(c => c.Status == Status.OK);
                    return new DtoTest { UserId = sg.Key, TotalSamples = ts, EvaluatedSamples = es, PercentageRealized = (int)(100.0 * ts / es) };
                });
```

Also, your percentage calculation will use C# integer division and not be close to correct, unless you convert to `double` first. You can cast back to `int` after the math.

If you really intended to return multiple results, and want to be efficient (and since I love extension methods), creating an extension method to count chained predicates for one pass:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static (int Cond1Count, int Cond2Count) Count2Chained<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, bool> cond1, Func<T, bool> cond2) {
        int cond1Count = 0;
        int cond2Count = 0;
        foreach (var s in src) {
            if (cond1(s)) {
                ++cond1Count;
                if (cond2(s))
                    ++cond2Count;
            }
        }
        return (cond1Count, cond2Count);
    }
}
```

Now you can count the sub-values in one pass and compute the third value:

```
var ans3 = myList.Select(s => {
            var (ts, es) = myList.Count2Chained(c => c.UserId == s.UserId, c => c.Status == Status.OK);
            return new DtoTest { UserId = s.UserId, TotalSamples = ts, EvaluatedSamples = es, PercentageRealized = (int)(100.0 * ts / es) };
        });
```

Of course, depending on the size of `myList`, you may still be better off calculating each answer once and then repeating them for the final answer:

```
var ansd = myList.GroupBy(s => s.UserId)
                 .Select(sg => {
                     var ts = sg.Count();
                     var es = sg.Count(c => c.Status == Status.OK);
                     return new { sg.Key, ts, es };
                 })
                 .ToDictionary(ste => ste.Key, ste => new DtoTest {
                    UserId = ste.Key,
                    TotalSamples = ste.ts,
                    EvaluatedSamples = ste.es,
                    PercentageRealized = (int)(100.0 * ste.ts / ste.es) });
var ans4 = myList.Select(s => ansd[s.UserId]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking care of each point, and putting together a more "dedicated" answer! In fact I need a `GroupBy` statement (I had forgotten to ask the question). On the calculation, yes we had identified that we would need to convert the result obtained through the function `.Count ()` (we are using the properties with `float`). One last note, I need to populate the `UserId` of  `DtoTest`, is there any problem in using `new DtoTest { ... UserId = s.FirstOrDefault().UserId`? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Igor since the `GroupBy` is by `UserId`, you can just use `sg.Key` to get the `UserId` of the group for the `DtoTest`. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Well, for this property it works fine (`Key`)... but the problem is that I have more properties that needed `.FirstOrDefault()` (like: UserName, etc). I do not see problem, because they will always be the same, ie I could group by any of these properties. Right?

Comment: Like: `.GroupBy(gb => new {gb => gb.UserId, gb.UserName})` ... `new DtoTest { ... UserId = s.Key.UserId, s.Key.UserName`

Comment: @Igor Yes, you could `GroupBy` the additional properties, but I would suggest using `FirstOrDefault()` in that case like you originally intended for the additional properties.

Answer (score 3):

Change the function delegate to use the already calculated values

```
myList.Select(s => {
    var result = new DtoTest() {
        TotalSamples = myList.Count(c => c.UserId == s.UserId),
        EvaluatedSamples = myList.Count(c => c.UserId == s.UserId && c.Status == Status.OK)
    };
    result.PercentageRealized = (result.TotalSamples / result.EvaluatedSamples) * 100;
    return result;
});
```

Comment: It was exactly what I understood ... how to create "variables" within the LINQ statement. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you were using an anonymous type this would be more complicated, but since `DtoTest` is a class, you could always move your math into the property.

```
public class DtoTest
{
    public float PercentageRealized
    {
        get { return (TotalSamples / EvaluatedSamples) * 100; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `PercentageRealized`  is that simple calculations, why not have the calculation in the property in the class, something like this inside the class DTOTest:

```
public float PercentageRealized => (TotalSamples / EvaluatedSamples) * 100;
```

Comment: Maybe! I thought about it, but the problem with doing this in the class is that it is a DTO (in my project they do not have any rule / calculation).

Comment: Yes, I understand your point, make sense, in this case I will go with Nkosi solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/53751408/20126

Answer (score 1):

first project to a tuple then project to your custom object:

```
 myList.Select(s => (tSample: myList.Count(c=> c.UserId == s.UserId), 
       eSample : myList.Count(c=> c.UserId == s.UserId && c.Status == Status.OK)))
      .Select(x => new DtoTest
      {
             TotalSamples = x.tSample,
             EvaluatedSamples = x.eSample,
             PercentageRealized = (x.tSample / x.eSample) * 100 
     });
```

or use an anonymous type:

```
myList.Select(s => new 
      {
        tSample = myList.Count(c=> c.UserId == s.UserId),
        eSample = myList.Count(c=> c.UserId == s.UserId && c.Status == Status.OK)
      })
      .Select(x => new DtoTest
      {
            TotalSamples = x.tSample,
            EvaluatedSamples = x.eSample,
            PercentageRealized = (x.tSample / x.eSample) * 100 
     });
```

Comment: This is like the implementation of `let`, only with `ValueTuple` instead of anonymous objects.

Comment: @NetMage Well, yes one can use anonymous types as well. included for completeness.

Comment: What I meant was in LINQ Query Syntax, the `let` operator is implemented by projecting (`Select`) to an anonymous type.

Comment: @Aomine Good approach! :)